# how to calculate monthly portfolio shares and dividends

Tags: python, django

I have a simple app that should track users stock portfolio. Basicly user may buy stocks like JNJ, AAPL or MCD. He can also sell some/all of them. Dividends might be reinvested instantly as they are paid out (same as if user did buy same stock for it's dividend value). I need to calculate this portfolio value on monthly basis.
**Easy example**:
Transactions:

```
+----------+--------+------------+-------+
| buy/sell | amount |    date    | price |
+----------+--------+------------+-------+
| buy      |      5 | 2015-01-01 |   $60 |
| sell     |      1 | 2015-03-01 |   $70 |
+----------+--------+------------+-------+
```

From this transactions I would like to get this dictionary of shares:

```
{
u'JNJ': {
    datetime.date(2015, 6, 1): Decimal('5.00000'), 
    datetime.date(2015, 7, 1): Decimal('5.00000'),
    datetime.date(2015, 8, 1): Decimal('4.00000'), 
    datetime.date(2015, 9, 1): Decimal('4.00000'), 
    datetime.date(2015, 10, 1): Decimal('4.00000')}
}
```

These are my shares by month. Lets say there was a  $0.75 dividend on 2015-08-21 and it on same day, I bought partial shares of JNJ on this date:

**Example with Dividends**:
Transactions:

```
+----------+--------+------------+-------+
| buy/sell | amount |    date    | price |
+----------+--------+------------+-------+
| buy      |      5 | 2015-01-01 |   $60 |
| sell     |      1 | 2015-03-01 |   $70 |
+----------+--------+------------+-------+
```

Dividends:

```
+------------+--------+-------+
|    date    | amount | price |
+------------+--------+-------+
| 2015-08-21 | 0.75   |    64 |
+------------+--------+-------+
```

When dividend was paid, I was holding 4 shares. For 4 shares I received 4*$0.75 and I bought 0.031393889 shares of JNJ.
Result:

```
{u'JNJ': 
    {  
        datetime.date(2015, 6, 1): Decimal('5.00000'), 
        datetime.date(2015, 7, 1): Decimal('5.00000'),
        datetime.date(2015, 8, 1): Decimal('4.031393889'),
        datetime.date(2015, 9, 1): Decimal('4.031393889'), 
        datetime.date(2015, 10, 1): Decimal('4.031393889')}
}
```

So this is what I have to calculate. There might be any number of transaction and dividends. There must be at least one Buy transaction, but dividends may not exist.
**These are my classes in models.py:**
Stock model representing Stock, for example JNJ.

```
class Stock(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField("Stock's name", max_length=200, default="")
    symbol = models.CharField("Stock's symbol", max_length=20, default="", db_index=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=30, decimal_places=5, null=True, blank=True)
```

Than I have StockTransaction, which represends object for one stock for one portfolio. Transactions are linked to StockTransaction, because drip applies to all Transactions.

```
class StockTransaction(models.Model):
    stock = models.ForeignKey('stocks.Stock')
    portfolio = models.ForeignKey(Portfolio, related_name="stock_transactions")
    drip = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Transaction class:

```
BUYCHOICE = [(True,'Buy'),(False,'Sell')]
class Transaction(models.Model):
    amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=5, validators=[MinValueValidator(Decimal('0.0001'))])
    buy = models.BooleanField(choices=BUYCHOICE, default=True)
    date = models.DateField('buy date')
    price = models.DecimalField('price per share', max_digits=20, decimal_places=5, validators=[MinValueValidator(Decimal('0.0001'))])

    stock_transaction = models.ForeignKey(StockTransaction, related_name="transactions", null=False)
```

and lastly Dividend class:

```
class Dividend(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField('pay date', db_index=True)
    amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=10)
    price = models.DecimalField('price per share', max_digits=20, decimal_places=10)
    stock_transaction = models.ManyToManyField('portfolio.StockTransaction', related_name="dividends", blank=True)
    stock = models.ForeignKey(Stock, related_name="dividends")
```

I've coded my method, but I do think there is a better way. My method is too long and takes to much time for portfolio with 106 stocks (each 5 transactions). Here is my method:

```
def get_portfolio_month_shares(portfolio_id):
    """
    Return number of dividends and shares per month respectfully in dict
    {symbol: {year: decimal, year: decimal} }
    :param portfolio: portfolio object for which to calculate shares and dividends
    :return: total dividends and amount of shares, respectfully
    """

    total_shares, total_dividends = {}, {}
    for stock_transaction in StockTransaction.objects.filter(portfolio_id=portfolio_id)\
            .select_related('stock').prefetch_related('dividends', 'transactions', 'stock__dividends'):
        shares = 0 #number of shares
        monthly_shares, monthly_dividends = {}, {}
        transactions = list(stock_transaction.transactions.all())
        first_transaction = transactions[0]

        for dividend in stock_transaction.stock.dividends.all():
            if dividend.date < first_transaction.date:
                continue
            try:
                #transactions that are older than last dividend
                while transactions[0].date < dividend.date:
                    if transactions[0].buy:
                        shares = shares + transactions[0].amount
                    else: #transaction is a sell
                        shares = shares - transactions[0].amount
                    monthly_shares[date(transactions[0].date.year, transactions[0].date.month, 1)] = shares
                    transactions.remove(transactions[0])
            except IndexError: #no more transactions
                pass
            if dividend in stock_transaction.dividends.all(): # if drip is active for dividend
                if dividend.price!=0:
                    shares += (dividend.amount * shares / dividend.price)
                    monthly_shares[date(dividend.date.year, dividend.date.month, 1)] = shares
            try:
                monthly_dividends[date(dividend.date.year, dividend.date.month, 1)] += shares * dividend.amount
            except KeyError:
                monthly_dividends[date(dividend.date.year, dividend.date.month, 1)] = shares * dividend.amount

        #fill blank months with 0
        if monthly_shares!={}:
            for dt in rrule.rrule(rrule.MONTHLY,
                                  dtstart=first_transaction.date,
                                  until=datetime.now() + relativedelta.relativedelta(months=1)):
                try:
                    monthly_shares[date(dt.year, dt.month, 1)]
                except KeyError: #keyerror on dt year
                    dt_previous = dt - relativedelta.relativedelta(months=1)
                    monthly_shares[date(dt.year, dt.month, 1)] = monthly_shares[date(dt_previous.year, dt_previous.month, 1)]
                try:
                    monthly_dividends[date(dt.year, dt.month, 1)]
                except KeyError:
                    monthly_dividends[date(dt.year, dt.month, 1)] = 0

        # for each transaction not covered by dividend for cycle
        if transactions:
            for transaction in transactions:
                for dt in rrule.rrule(rrule.MONTHLY,
                              dtstart=transaction.date,
                              until=datetime.now() + relativedelta.relativedelta(months=1)):
                    if transaction.buy:
                        try:
                            monthly_shares[date(dt.year, dt.month, 1)] += transaction.amount
                        except KeyError:
                            monthly_shares[date(dt.year, dt.month, 1)] = transaction.amount
                    else: #sell
                        monthly_shares[date(dt.year, dt.month, 1)] -= transaction.amount
        total_dividends[stock_transaction.stock.symbol] = monthly_dividends
        total_shares[stock_transaction.stock.symbol] = monthly_shares
    return total_dividends, total_shares
```

**Description**:
First for cycle - for each stock in portfolio.
Second for cycle - for each stock's dividend
this line `if dividend in stock_transaction.dividends.all()` checks if dividends are reinvested. There exists m2m relation between stock_transaction and dividend objects if they are.
for cycle with rrule fills up blank months to previous month value.

---

**EDIT1:**
I already optimized number of sql queries with django-debug-toolbar (4 sql queries needed). My code is slow probably because of many objects and large dictionaries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a shot in the dark here (I'm not familiar with stock dividends, so I can't comment on the math).

It looks like this could be your bottleneck:

```
    for dividend in stock_transaction.stock.dividends.all():
```

You select_related on `stock` and you prefetch_related on `dividends`, but you don't grab `stock__dividends`. You can check whether or not this is the bottleneck using the [Django Debug Toolbar](https://github.com/django-debug-toolbar/django-debug-toolbar).

If this repeating query is the root problem, then you may try adding it in:

```
    ...select_related('stock', 'stock__dividends')...
```

Comment: I already optimized sql queries with debug-toolbar. I have stock__dividends in prefetch_related() and it does not make any extra sql queries on line you mentioned. Thanks for answer though. I will update question that I have already optimized sql queries and that whole method `get_portfolio_month_shares(portfolio_id)` only makes 4 queries (1 sql query for StockTransaction and 3 to prefetch_related).

Comment: Hmm...That's never a good thing when the database query is NOT the bottleneck. You may have to offer a bounty to get a Python expert's advice. Or just increase the RAM in your server.

Comment: Ok, thanks for suggestion. Probably I try some kind of django profiler first and if it wont help, I'll try bounty offer. Thanks again for your time and help.